# The pdf of a sum of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $f_{x,y}(x,y)= \frac{1}{8}$ for  $-2< x<2$ and $0<y<2$. Find $f(z)$ where $Z= X+Y$.

This is what I have so far, but I don't think it is right.

for $-2<z<2$,

$f(z)= \int_{-2}^z \frac{1}{8} dx= \frac{z}{8} +\frac {1}{4}$

and for $2<z<4$,

$f(z)=\int_{z-2}^2 \frac{1}{8} dx= \frac {1}{2} - \frac{z}{8}$

I think I need to break this up into three regions;

$-2<z<0$, $0<z<2$, $2<z<4$, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that $x\in[-2;2], y\in[0;2]$, then use the convolution:
$$\begin{align}
f_{X+Y}(z) & = \int_{\Bbb R} f_{X,Y}(x,z-x) \mathbf 1_{x\in[-2;2], z-x\in[0;2], z\in[-2;4]}\operatorname d x
\\[1ex] & = \int_{\Bbb R} \tfrac 1 8\; \mathbf 1_{x\in[-2;2], z-x\in[0;2], z\in[-2;4]}\operatorname d x
\\[3ex]
& x\in[-2;2], z-x\in[0;2], z\in[-2;4]
\\[1ex] \iff & x\in[-2;2] , x\in[z-2;z] , z\in[-2; 4]
\\[1ex] \iff &(z\in[-2;0),x\in[-2;z])\cup\color{navy}{(z\in[0;2),x\in[z-2; z])}\cup(z\in[2;4],x\in[z-2;2])
\\[3ex]
f_{X+Y}(z) & = \mathbf 1_{z\in[-2;0)} \int_{-2}^{z} \tfrac 1 8\; \operatorname d x
 +\color{navy}{\mathbf 1_{z\in[0;2)} \int_{z-2}^{z} \tfrac 1 8\; \operatorname d x}
 +\mathbf 1_{z\in[2;4]} \int_{z-2}^{2} \tfrac 1 8\; \operatorname d x
\\[1ex]
 & = (\tfrac z 8+\tfrac 1 4)\mathbf 1_{z\in[-2;0)} 
 +\color{navy}{\mathbf 1_{z\in[0;2)} \int_{z-2}^{z} \tfrac 1 8\; \operatorname d x}
 +(\tfrac 1 2-\tfrac z 8)\mathbf 1_{z\in[2;4]} 
\end{align}$$

The bit in $\color{navy}{\text{navy}}$ is the integral on the interval that you missed.  Evaluate that and you're done.

---

**PS:** If you haven't encountered it before, an *indicator function* is a piecewise function that evaluates to one whenever the condition in the subscript is true, and zero elsewhere.

$$\mathbf 1_{k\in A,h\in B} =\begin{cases}1& : k\in A\wedge h\in B\\0& :\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

And such.

Answer (score 0):

You first want $ F_Z(z) $. This corresponds to an integral of the joint pdf over the half plane $ x+y \leq z$. This intersects with the rectangle to form either a set with no area, a triangle, a trapezoid, or the whole rectangle, depending on $ z$. As you noticed, it first becomes a trapezoid when $ z> 0$, and becomes the whole rectangle when $ z \geq 2$. Your cdf will be the areas of these intersections times 1/8 and then your pdf will be the derivative of that.

Alternately, $ Z $ is the sum of a uniform variable on [-2,2] with an independent uniform variable on [0,2], so its pdf is the convolution of these two pdfs.